# How to Implement Simple, Quick HMAC on Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c, can-bus

Hi I am a research student working on securing the communications in Controlled Area Networks (CANs), and I am using Arduinos to simulate one of these CANs.

My goal is to use HMAC to implement message authentication of packets, and the algorithm **must** be *very fast* (I was originally thinking of using FNV1a). However, there are no Arduino libraries for this (I found one, but it uses SHA which will most likely be too slow for CAN). I don't have a *lot* of practice with cryptography and hash algorithms, only usage of them.

So basically, I need help writing a FNV or FNV1a function in C. The message for input will be a key (obviously) concatenated with a string (char array). Also, I need the hash to be between 128 and 256 bits for sufficient security.

Just as a side note: A CAN message/packet looks like **7df#02010d** and the actual data part, **010d** (two bytes) is the char array I will be using. For example, as integers, the array for **010d** would be {1, 13}.

--

I also know this message applies more to cryptography than Arduino, but I figured someone from this community might have more experience with my particular task, or even have/know of a library I can use that I hadn't found.

-Thanks

---

*EDIT:* I found [this FNV1a implementation in C/C++](http://create.stephan-brumme.com/fnv-hash/) that might work. But I have not tested it yet.

Comment: HMAC = [Hash-based Message Authentication Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended finding a Arduino library called **Spritz** which can be found here:
https://github.com/abderraouf-adjal/ArduinoSpritzCipher

Also, for anyone else who comes across this task, here is a *very simple* Hashed Message Authentication Code (HMAC) example I scrapped together:
https://github.com/zach-king/ArduinoStash/blob/master/src/Spritz_HMAC/Spritz_HMAC.ino

This library supports encryption as well, which is nice, but not needed in my case.

--EDIT--
The SpritzCipher library was actually too slow (about a 50% reduction in network speed) so I must try a different approach. I have found a MD5 library for Arduino which I will try next:
https://github.com/tzikis/ArduinoMD5

Comment: How did ArduinoMD5 implementation go?

Comment: @mixdev It's been a couple of years now so I don't remember the exact details of the performance, but I believe I did end up going with the MD5 implementation. MD5 was sufficient for speed and bit-length security for my purposes.